# Why use useMutation in React Query?

Tags: react-query

I am new to react query.

I found out that using useQuery can reduce requests by caching.

But it's hard to understand why I use useMutation.

```
axios.post('/user', { name, ... })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err);
```

```
const { mutate, isLoading, ... } = useMutation(fetcher, {
  onSuccess: (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  onError: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Both codes handle successful requests and errors.

Isn't `queryClient.invalidateQueries('queryKey');` also covered by axios then() function?

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difference in what happens to the backend state. In a query the intention is that you're requesting a particular dataset from some source. The request does not change any backend state, and any re-requests for the data will also not cause a change to backend state.

In a mutation the intention is to create some change in the backend state. (e.g. creating a new record in a database, or updating an existing record).

It's the equivalent of a read (query) vs write (mutation) operation

Comment: Thank you for answer. The 'backend state' is the state recognized by the frontend?

Comment: It's the state which is only available via async calls.

Answer (score 0):

At least useMutations provides a lot of useful stuff like loading state, error, etc. under the hood.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Outside of returning useful mutation states (isPending, isSuccess, error), as of React Query v5 you can now track a mutation from another component, with help of useMutationState. In some cases this can eliminate the need for a store/context to expose these states to other components, or passing them down as props, as any component can just access any mutation with useMutationState, provided you specified the mutationKey